# iPhone userAcceleration not zero

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-motion

Why are the values of accelerations (userAcceleration) not zero, even if the device is at rest? I using the following code to determine accelerations by x,y,z:

```
motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current!) { [weak self] data, error in
    if let error = error {
        print("Error occurred: \(error)")
    } else {
        if let data = data,
           let weakSelf = self {                   
            weakSelf.userAccelerationByX.text = "\(data.userAcceleration.x)"
            weakSelf.userAccelerationByY.text = "\(data.userAcceleration.y)"
            weakSelf.userAccelerationByZ.text = "\(data.userAcceleration.z)"                   
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

iPhone uses magnets to determine accelerations, so it is very sensitive to everything. Even when you put your phone down, there are still a lot of things can affect its magnetic and movement.

Comment: So, how i can normalize values?

Comment: What do you use that values for? You can compare them with a defined values. e.g: `if fabs(userAcceleration.x) < 0.1 {// not so much move ...} else {// move a lot ...}`